# "Deficiency" or "Deficiencies"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, singular-vs-plural

I was wondering which form of the word "[deficiency](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/deficiency?q=Deficiency%20)" is grammatically preferred in the following example and why?

> 1. Students mostly have **deficiency** in math. 
>    2. Students mostly have **deficiencies** in math.

I think logically, the plural form is better sounding, but I see no reason the former case is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, "deficiency" is singular and needs an article:
Students mostly have **a** deficiency in math.

That use of "mostly" is a bit informal. A more careful expression might be
Most students have a deficiency in math.

The sentence with "deficiencies" as a plural is good too. Whether you use the singular or plural depends on how you are thinking of "deficiency", and either way seems valid.

Comment: Well, how about the latter sentence @Jacl O'Flaherty? I mean "Students mostly have **deficiencies** in math".

Comment: That sentence is good. I edited my answer a bit.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the article-less sequence [***have deficiency in***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+deficiency+in&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20deficiency%20in%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Chave%20deficiency%20in%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: To me, rather than "have deficiency in" without an article, I would say "are deficient in".

Answer (score 1):

Syntactically speaking, singular ***deficiency*** and plural ***deficiencies*** are both fine in OP's context. But I wouldn't bother with either of them, because ***idiomatically*** the context [shouldn't arise anyway...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have%20deficiency%20in%20math%2Chave%20deficiencies%20in%20math%2Care%20deficient%20in%20math&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Care%20deficient%20in%20math%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Care%20deficient%20in%20math%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

...so I suggest you ditch the "slangy" ***mostly***<sup>1</sup>, and rephrase to *[they] **are deficient in maths*** (or ***math*** if you're siding with Americans rather than Brits! :)

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that ***mostly*** is somewhat ambiguous here anyway. Are ***most students*** deficient in maths, or do ***most deficiencies*** relate to numeracy (rather than, say, *literacy*)?